# Reloading registration form on failed validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a registration form view stored in my database. User clicks on link to show registration form. form looks like so:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action = ".">
                        <label>Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="" required><br></label>
                        <label>Email:<input type="email" name="email" value="" required><br></label>
                        <label>Password:<input type="password" name="pass" value="" required><br></label>


                        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_register"/>
                    </form>
```

controller called index.php grabs the do_register value from the action and proceeds to process validation.

```
if($action == 'do_register'){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 if(empty($email) || empty($pass) || empty($name)){
 $error = 'All fields required';
 $view = 'view.php';
 }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
 $error = "Please enter a valid email.";
 $view = "view.php";

 }else{
 $user = insertUser($name, $email, $pass);

 if(!$user){
 $error = "There was an error. Please try again";
 $view = "view.php";

 }else{
$error = "Thank you for registering!";
$view = 'view.php';
 }
 }
 }
```

When it reloads the view it just shows my error message and does not show the registration form to try again. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I also have the required attributes on the form disabled.

Comment: Did you try to use the require_once to get the form when the form was not validated?

Comment: no.but the form is in the database so I somehow have to get the page to navigate to the index.php and send the action a value on fail? the form is not a .php of itself.

Comment: to initially get the form my code looks like this. if ($action == 'reg') {
  
   $page = getPage($action);
 $title = $page['title'];
 $content = $page['content'];
 $view = 'view.php';
 
 }

Comment: This isn't a good way to create a simple form like that. You just need to create a form, use isset and check if the form was validated. Why use database to show de form?

Comment: I have to make a completely dynamic website for school. not my choice tbh.

Comment: How do you are getting the form in the website?

Comment: if ($action == 'reg') { $page = getPage($action); $title = $page['title']; $content = $page['content']; $view = 'view.php'; }

Comment: Is `$page['content']` the variable which collects from view from database .?

Comment: Show the base of you code. You are getting some variables that you didn't show. The problem is basic. You are running a $_POST and the form only is showed when you are not running this request. You just need to add a variable when the form don't validate. Something like $validation = false, and after just put a conditional to show the form if the $validation is false... This is simple, but you need to show the logic of your code.

Comment: -Adeel yes.    -Iago that really is all my code. I got it working with a header redirect but it doesnt show the error message.

Comment: header('Location: index.php?action=reg'); this will reload the view but the $error is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you reloading the page. There is batter practice to use in session.

use `$_SESSION["error"]` instead of `$error`.